# Blurred interface (wrong interface scale)

Tags: interface, windows

I've just installed Blender 2.8 (also check 2.76 and 2.79) and interface looks quite weird (windows 10, FHD res).

- menu bar not visible although application is displayed in fullscreen
  mode
- bottom of the window is cut and hidden a little bit by windows
  toolbar
- when I want to click something in the menu mouse have to be a
  little bit lower then an element I wanted to click

[image]

Mouse was in the red field.